# How do you do a Slice (use ix, loc, iloc) operation on a Pandas Object excluding some specified indexes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Many `ix`, `loc`, `iloc` operation you specify indexes which you want to choose. I want do the opposite. There are few columns I want to exclude and select the rest. How do I do this. I.e., specify the indices which needs excluded than included.

E.g. some pseudo code

```
a.iloc[~1:3, :]
a.loc[~['A', 'B'], :]
```

I am looking for both **performance**, **memory usage** and **succinctness** as in the above pseudo code.

NB: The DataFrames are big with large about of data alone one axis and relatively little data along the others.

Answer (score 1):

You can either `drop` OR select the ones you want:

```
df.drop(df.columns[[1, 2]], axis=1, inplace=True)

# drop by Name
df1 = df1.drop(['D', 'E'], axis=1)

## Select the ones you want
df1 = df[['a','d']]
```

There's also a new [difference](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html) you can call on index. So everything except col D and col E:

```
 df2 = df[df.columns.difference(['D', 'E'])]
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

***use [`difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html)***

Suppose you had the slice `[1:3]` you wanted to get all rows not in that slice.  Use `difference` and `loc`

```
idx = df.index.difference(df.index[1:3])
df.loc[idx]
```

We can do the same thing if we know the row names

```
idx = df.index.difference(['A', 'B'])
df.loc[idx]
```

***old answer***

use `np.r_` to create slices for `iloc`

```
df.iloc[np.r_[0:1, 3:], :]
```

For `loc`... use `drop`

```
df.drop(['A', 'B'])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the index of columns you want to exclude, just slice the column-array extracted from df.columns for the columns you want in your dataframe. Eg:

```
df[df.columns[2:5]]
```

If you do not know the index, but their names, just remove it from the column-array, again extracted from df.columns. Eg:

```
df[df.columns[(df.columns != "col_A") & (df.columns != "col_B")]]
```